# Difficulties in running applications in Java Wireless Toolkit

Tags: java, java-me, java-wireless-toolkit

I have been trying to run Java Mobile applications through the `Java Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2_01`. These applications are located in the `apps` directory of the  `Java Wireless Toolkit`.
I'm facing with this error:

> Gtk-Message: 15:13:31.508: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library
>   /home/ndanga/Virtuel/Java/Micro/WTK2.5.2/bin/sublime.so which might
>   have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
>   It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c
>   ', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   /home/ndanga/Virtuel/Java/Micro/WTK2.5.2/bin/sublime.so:
>   /home/ndanga/Virtuel/Java/Micro/WTK2.5.2/bin/sublime.so: mauvaise
>   classe ELF : ELFCLASS32 (Possible cause: architecture word width
>   mismatch)     at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)     at
>   java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)   at
>   com.sun.kvem.Sublime.(Sublime.java:29)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)  at
>   com.sun.kvem.Lime.createLime(Lime.java:40)    at
>   com.sun.kvem.KVMBridge.(KVMBridge.java:46)  at
>   com.sun.kvem.KVMBridge.getBridge(KVMBridge.java:37)   at
>   com.sun.kvem.midp.MIDP.run(MIDP.java:699)     at
>   com.sun.kvem.environment.EmulatorInvoker.runEmulatorImpl(EmulatorInvoker.java:107)
>     at
>   com.sun.kvem.environment.EmulatorInvoker.main(EmulatorInvoker.java:135)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   com.sun.kvem.environment.JVM.main(JVM.java:103)

Can I have some help? Please.

Answer (score 0):

The Java Wireless Toolkit requires a 32-bit version of Java to run, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60260530/5269447 for a step by step guide to installing it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'll try the solution you propose.