# Developing a J2ME application on Ubuntu in the current year?

Tags: ubuntu, java-me

I recently dug out an old phone that runs J2ME applications and would like to write applications for it, in my attempts to get the SDK running with Netbeans and figure out the emulator I've hit many roadblocks caused by various compatibility issues due to the toolchain being so old.

So my question is this: What is the most straightforward, minimalist way for me to compile a J2ME hello world application. I don't need an IDE and am fine without an emulator, I just want to use Ubuntu to produce a `.jar` that will run on my phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two years ago I used the following steps to develop with emulator.

Download [JDK 1.6 32 bits](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html), uncompress, mv to /usr/lib/jvm/, chown to root.

Download [Sun Java Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2_01](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javame-419430.html), install and set java executable path to /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_45/bin

```
sudo apt-get install libxi6:i386 libxt6:i386
./WTK2.5.2/bin/ktoolbar
```

From this point onwards you can focus on how ktoolbar handles projects. IDE project setup should use CLDC and MIDP libs under ktoolbar folder structure.

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer was very straightforward and headache-free

Comment: 2023 folk here! I got a JavaME phone too just for fun and looking for a way to write small apps for it and stumbled upon this SO answer, thank you so much!